Setting up React Native Project with Nx is not loading Local Image Assets in Android
I have setup a project using
npx create-nx-workspace@latest your-workspace-name --preset=react-native --appName=your-app-name

and created nx App
nx g @nx/react-native:app apps/<your-app-name>

and nx library
nx g @nx/react-native:lib libs/<your-lib-name>

Then I added few assets in local branch
in lib/lib_name/src/assets folder.
But when I run android app either from Android Studio or with command. This assets are not visible in Android. But they are being loaded in iOS app.
